# Did Fukawa actually just explode somehow? If not, how did she die?

Tags: danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc

In the bad ending for Danganronpa: Trigger Happy Havoc

> Naegi, Byakuya, Hagakure, and Asahina, are shown together in some sort of four-way marriage, with Byakuya holding Fukawa's memorial photo.

It's never explained within the game itself how Fukawa died during this time, except that she can't have been murdered or committed suicide. According to [some people on Twitter](https://twitter.com/DanganTrivia/status/810872963482480640), Kodaka said in an interview at some point that "she just exploded somehow". However, I can't find any actual source for the interview, or anything beyond casual references to it from English-speaking fans. So:

*Did* Kodaka actually say somewhere in an interview that Fukawa just randomly exploded somehow? And if not, has there ever been any explanation given in any part of the series as to how she might have died?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [the original interview](https://dengekionline.com/elem/000/000/360/360827/index-3.html). It's been fan-translated a few times, but [this](https://fukawawawa.tumblr.com/post/62749005164/i-found-this-interview-through-this-post-and) seems to be the post that other internet users are referencing.

> **Kodaka (Writer):** *Speaking of Fukawa, there were a lot of times I didn’t know what to do with her so I just took her out of the picture. **She just dies for some reason, she just explodes for some reason (lol)**. Really she shouldn’t have been in the bath scene either, there’s no way she’d be in there, but she’s there for that CG.*
>
> **Komatsuzaki (Character Designer + Artist):** *That was just for fanservice though.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ryogo Narita talks about "Danganronpa"! Published the full version of the dialogue plan with the developer](https://fukawawawa.tumblr.com/post/62749005164/i-found-this-interview-through-this-post-and) from https://dengekionline.com/elem/000/000/360/360827/index-5.html</sup></sub>

Comment: Ah-ha, that is the interview I was hoping to find! Shame there's no more serious answer out there, but I suppose I shouldn't be taking that ending too seriously in the first place.